# Receiving Email on an ec2 public dns hostname

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

While creating an aws instance, each instance is associated a public dns - (ec2-13-116-93-27.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com ).

I want to know is there anyway I can receive email on this domain ( for e.g on address like - admin@ec2-13-126-93-77.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com ?
Or is there anyway I can setup additional records (like mx records) on that domain.

I now that this domain is allocated for entirely different reasons than what I am hoping to achieve, but if there's some way to do it, I would appreciate it very much.
Thank you.

Comment: Your domain can change if you have to stop and start your server. Receiving email there probably isn't a great idea. Get a domain and set up MX records - domains are cheap.

Comment: I know, I do own a few domains, I just had a use case for what I wanted, but Anyways seems there's no possibility to achieve what I want so doesn't matter now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have control of that domain, so there is no way you can create any DNS records in it. That said, you could easily procures your own domain and create MX records pointing to this hostname or wherever else you'd like.